# Should've kept or should've keep

Tags: word-usage

Let's say I want to say something I should've do, do I use the past tense or normal

I should've kept the information /
I should've keep the information

Which one is right and why?

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

**should** is the past tense of modal verb **shall**.  When forming a statement about the past using that modal verb, it is combined with auxiliary verb **have** and the *past-participle* of the lexical verb. The lexical verb here is **keep** and its past participle form is **kept**.

**should have kept**

The auxiliary verb **have** never partners with the infinitive.

Compare:

weep, wept
sweep, swept

> I should have **taken** the earlier train.

Answer (score 0):

Past tense. Since you are referring to something that has happened in the past, you should use the past tense of the work 'keep'. 
So,

```
I should've kept the information.
```

is correct.